# ASP.NET: WebApi (ApiController) vs OData (ODataController)

Tags: asp.net, web-services, rest, odata, crud

I am about to embark on a new project that will basically provide CRUD and enquiry forms for a database. The plan is to provide access to the data via web services of some sort, along with custom client applications for Windows and iOS; there will also be some forms provided on the web for access from devices without the custom client installed.

As a totally "greenfield" project, I have an opportunity to look at the latest technologies and as a .NET developer I am considering the use of either WebApi or OData for the web services. Thing is, I am struggling to determine which would be a better fit.

As I understand it, WebApi is better for CRUD due to the REST interfaces it provides. However, given that there may be some enquiries and/or reporting within the application interfaces, I am also led to believe that querying and joining the data would be better achieved using OData. I do not really want to expose multiple endpoints (though it is not totally ruled out).

Can anybody provide any opinion as to which of these might be a better fit so as to help me decide between the two.

Thanks.

Comment: I am facing a similar dilemma as described here.  Given it's been two years since your post, could you share what you've learned?  I'd really appreciate the opportunity to learn from your experience.